# FeathersJS - add useUnifiedTopology to MongoDB

Tags: feathersjs

I'm using FeathersJS with MondoDB via `feathers-mongo`

I want to somehow pass `useUnifiedToplogy:true` to the connector's settings, however it doesn't seem to be exposed in the generated service (`feathers generate service`)

This is my `logging.class.ts`

```
import { Db } from 'mongodb';
import { Service, MongoDBServiceOptions } from 'feathers-mongodb';
import { Application } from '../../declarations';
import {Paginated, Params} from "@feathersjs/feathers";

export class Logging extends Service {
  constructor(options: Partial<MongoDBServiceOptions>, app: Application) {
    super(options);

    const client: Promise<Db> = app.get('mongoClient');

    client.then(db => {
      this.Model = db.collection('users');
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a `mongodb.ts` at `root`

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import { Application } from './declarations';

export default function (app: Application) {
  const connection = app.get('mongodb');
  const database = connection.substr(connection.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  const mongoClient = MongoClient.connect(connection, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(client => client.db(database));

  app.set('mongoClient', mongoClient);
}
```